# Mongodb config file option for authentication

Tags: mac-osx, mongodb

I'm trying to start mongodb(3.0.2) with authentication enabled on mac osx 10.10 from the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/). Starting monodb manually with `--auth` works and starts without any error. I installed mongodb using homebrew and want to place the auth switch in configuration file. I could not find anything appropriate in [Configuration Options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/). I tried `auth: true` in the config file but mongodb failed to start.

Anybody has got it working, I'm looking for config file option(rather than --auth) to run mongodb with authentication enabled to prevent anonymous access.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually

```
authorization: enabled
```

in you config file it needs to be under `security:` and your config file should look like

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

For more information see :
http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization

Answer (score 0):

Close, it's actually this:

```
auth=true
```

Also, if you're running a replicaset and enable the keyfile, it will enable auth as well.

```
keyFile=/etc/mongod.keyfile
```

Comment: `Unrecognized option: auth=true`, may be this worked upto 2.4.